# Using the <router-outlet> in components other than the application component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

If we use the [`<router-outlet>`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) in a component (Any component) and then put a [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) to another component within that component, does the link always render the component linked to in the [`<router-outlet>`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) of the currently active component?

In other words are component [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) attributes always paired with the [`<router-outlet>`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) within a component?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, please reformulate or add a concrete example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`<router-outlet>`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) is not linked to the component.  It is linked to the child routes of the component to which it resides.

A [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) just navigates the Applications assigned routes

For example suppose you have these routes

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
    { path: 'details', component: AccountDetails
  ]
];
```

Your AppComponent looks something like this we'll say

```js
@Component({
  template: `
<div>
  <a routerLink='/home'>Home</a>
  <a routerLink='/account'>Account</a>
  <a routerLink-'/account/details>Account Details</a>
</div>
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
`
})
```

Let's say your AccountComponent is something like this

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      Account Name {{ name }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <a routerLink='/home'>Home</a>
      <a routerLink='/account'>Account</a>
      <a routerLink-'/account/details>Account Details</a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
  })
```

When you click on Account Details, it will load the account component with the details in the router-outlet of the account component.

When you click on home it will load the app component with the home component loaded in the router-outlet of that component. It loads the component in the router-outlet based on where it sites in the route tree.

Note: This is not production code and should not be used as such.

Comment: I was searching for this for couple of hours ... very nice answer ... thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jeyiwh

Make sure you're importing the angular router in your app.module.ts